# grunt-contrib-proxy does not get called for angularjs $http services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use grunt-contrib-proxy with grunt:serve (localhost:9000) so that I can call services on my webserver (localhost:80/myserver).  I can see that proxyRequest gets called when each file is loading (no match so skips that though) but then when I call a webservice proxyRequest is not called.  Here is my config:

```
 connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    proxies: [
      {
        context: 'myserver',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 80,
        https: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        xforward: false
      }
    ],
    options: {
      open: {
        appName: '<%= yeoman.defaultBrowser %>'
      },
      base:[
        '.tmp',
        appConfig.app
      ],
      middleware: function (connect,options) {
        if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
          options.base = [options.base];
        }

        // Setup the proxy
        var middlewares = [require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest];

        // Serve static files.
        options.base.forEach(function(base) {
          middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
        });

        middlewares.push(connect().use('/.tmp/styles',connect.static('./.tmp/styles')));
        middlewares.push(connect().use('/.tmp/images', connect.static('./.tmp/images')));
        middlewares.push(connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')));

        // Make directory browse-able.
        var directory = options.directory || options.base[options.base.length - 1];
        middlewares.push(connect.directory(directory));

        return middlewares;
      }
    }
  },
```

Here is my task:

```
 grunt.task.run([
  'clean:server',
  'wiredep',
  'less:dist',
  'sprite:all',
  'sprite:json',
  'copy:styles',
  'copy:fonts',
  'autoprefixer',
  'configureProxies:livereload',
  'connect:livereload',
  'watch'
]);
```

Comment: Change context to '/myserver/'

Comment: I still get "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error and it says the origin is localhost:9000.  The way I understand this module is it changes the origin to be localhost.

Comment: Run it with --debug and look at the output. Does the output state that

Comment: The output shows proxy getting called when downloading files but nothing at all is logged on service requests.

Comment: I found first issue.  I am using absolute urls in my $http.get.  for some reason when using an abs url then proxy never runs.  If I make that a relative url then proxy runs and finds a match but for some reason I then get a 404 not found as it is looking for the web service at localhost:9000